# Permission Denied while trying to Find file

Tags: linux, permissions, find

I was trying to find a library by using `find . -name "*libcurl"` or `find . -name "*libcurl.so"` command.

I get a list of messages with permission denied, not sure whether that means the file couldn't be found or there is something else

```
find: ‘./var/lib/sudo’: Permission denied   
find: ‘./root’: Permission denied
find: ‘./etc/polkit-1/localauthority’: Permission denied
find: ‘./etc/ssl/private’: Permission denied
find: ‘./tmp/.vnc-vncservice’: Permission denied
find: ‘./tmp/systemd-private-1f2e202de1f9401abdddd0375b82dc2c-systemd-timesyncd.service-lg23DT’: Permission denied
find: ‘./sys/kernel/debug’: Permission denied
find: ‘./run/udisks2’: Permission denied
find: ‘./run/lightdm’: Permission denied
find: ‘./run/systemd/inaccessible’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/tty/driver’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/1/task/1/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/1/task/1/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/19/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/21/task/21/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/21/task/21/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/21/task/21/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/21/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/21/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/21/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/21/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/22/task/22/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/22/task/22/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/22/task/22/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/22/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/22/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/22/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/22/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/23/task/23/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/23/task/23/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/23/task/23/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/23/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/23/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/23/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/23/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/24/task/24/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/24/task/24/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/24/task/24/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/24/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/24/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/24/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/24/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/26/task/26/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/26/task/26/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/26/task/26/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/26/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/26/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/26/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/26/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/27/task/27/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/27/task/27/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/27/task/27/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/27/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/27/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/27/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/27/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/28/task/28/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/28/task/28/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/28/task/28/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/28/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/28/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/28/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/28/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/32/task/32/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/32/task/32/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/32/task/32/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/32/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/32/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/32/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/32/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/33/task/33/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/33/task/33/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/33/task/33/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/33/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/33/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/33/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/33/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/34/task/34/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/34/task/34/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/34/task/34/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/34/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/34/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/34/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/34/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/35/task/35/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/35/task/35/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/35/task/35/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/35/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/35/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/35/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/35/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/36/task/36/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/36/task/36/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/36/task/36/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/36/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/36/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/36/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/36/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/37/task/37/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/37/task/37/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/37/task/37/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/37/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/37/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/37/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/37/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/38/task/38/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/38/task/38/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/38/task/38/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/38/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/38/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/38/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/38/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/39/task/39/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/39/task/39/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/39/task/39/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/39/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/39/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/39/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/39/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/40/task/40/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/40/task/40/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/40/task/40/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/40/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/40/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/40/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/40/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/41/task/41/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/41/task/41/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/41/task/41/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/41/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/41/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/41/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/41/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/44/task/44/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/44/task/44/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/44/task/44/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/44/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/44/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/44/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/44/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/45/task/45/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/45/task/45/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/45/task/45/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/45/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/45/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/45/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/45/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/55/task/55/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/55/task/55/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/55/task/55/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/55/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/55/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/55/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/55/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/56/task/56/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/56/task/56/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/56/task/56/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/56/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/56/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/56/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/56/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/57/task/57/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/57/task/57/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/57/task/57/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/57/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/57/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/57/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/57/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/58/task/58/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/58/task/58/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/58/task/58/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/58/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/58/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/58/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/58/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/60/task/60/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/60/task/60/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/60/task/60/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/60/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/60/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/60/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/60/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/61/task/61/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/61/task/61/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/61/task/61/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/61/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/61/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/61/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/61/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/62/task/62/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/62/task/62/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/62/task/62/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/62/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/62/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/62/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/62/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/63/task/63/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/63/task/63/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/63/task/63/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/63/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/63/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/63/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/63/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/64/task/64/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/64/task/64/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/64/task/64/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/64/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/64/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/64/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/64/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/65/task/65/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/65/task/65/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/982/task/982/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/982/fd’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/982/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/982/fdinfo’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/982/ns’: Permission denied
find: ‘./lost+found’: Permission denied
```

Do I require something additional like sudo or something like that. I am basically running into another issue review details in [Error while deploying code to Raspberry Pi: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52172272/error-while-deploying-code-to-raspberry-pi-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lcurl?noredirect=1#comment91346742_52172272).

I was asked to see whether I have the file called libcurl.so while trying to find that I run into the issue.

**Edit:1**
When I use sudo(`sudo find . -name "*libcurl"`) I see the following;

```
find: ‘./run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
find: ‘./proc/650/task/650/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘./proc/650/net’: Invalid argument
```

**Edit:2**
After trying `sudo find / -name *libcurl*` as suggested by @kenlukas, I get the following;

```
    /opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/11.3/SystemFiles/Links/CURLLink/LibraryResources/Linux-ARM/libcurllink.so
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3-gnutls:armhf.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3-gnutls:armhf.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3-gnutls:armhf.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3-gnutls:armhf.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3:armhf.triggers
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3:armhf.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3:armhf.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3:armhf.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3:armhf.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libcurl3-gnutls:armhf.triggers
/var/cache/apt/archives/libcurl3_7.52.1-5+deb9u6_armhf.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libcurl4-openssl-dev_7.52.1-5+deb9u6_armhf.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libcurl3-gnutls_7.52.1-5+deb9u6_armhf.deb
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
find: ‘/proc/650/task/650/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/650/net’: Invalid argument
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl-gnutls.so.4
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl.so.4.4.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl-gnutls.so.3
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.4.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl.so.3
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl.so.4
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libcurl3
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libcurl3-gnutls
/usr/share/doc/libcurl3
/usr/share/doc/libcurl3-gnutls
```

Comment: You don't have the proper permissions for those directories.  Using `sudo` should clear that up.  Depending on what flavor of Linux you're using, you may want to look in `/usr/lib64` as well.

Comment: Thanks I am trying to send commands to my Pi, whose operating syetem is debian stretch

Comment: When I use sudo I see the following;
`pi@raspberrypi:/ $ sudo find . -name "*libcurl"  
find: ‘./run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied  
find: ‘./proc/650/task/650/net’: Invalid argument  
find: ‘./proc/650/net’: Invalid argument  `

Comment: try looking under `/usr/lib/` on Debian

Comment: I just looked under lib didn't find the file, I hope that is what you were asking me to look or was there anything specific?

Comment: try this `sudo find / -name *libcurl*`

Comment: It might be a good idea to avoid recursing into procfs and sysfs and the like - see `-xdev` option.  Of course, you'll now need to list all the filesystem roots as directories to search.  (Or just use `locate` if you've installed one - it will be much faster).

Comment: @jww slightly confused with the findings that people indeed ask these kind of questions, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25234419/10008499

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `find`, use `locate` command

```
locate libcurl.so
```

locate keeps a database of files on your computer and gives much faster results, unless that *.so file was created very recently.

If you don't want to see the messages in find result, read this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25234419/10008499