# sudo find / -name filename gives invalid argument error

Tags: find

I just set up a new dedicated server using AlmaLinux 8 and WHM/cpanel.

My other dedicated servers all use Centos 7 and WHM/cpanel.

In SSH as root, on Centos servers, I have always used
`sudo find / -name filename`
to find files on the servers

On AlmaLinux 8 in SSH as root
`sudo find / -name filename`
gives me the following errors  (the process number changes for different `sudo find / -name` inquiries )

```
find: ‘/proc/929745/task/929745/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/929745/net’: Invalid argument
```

For some `sudo find / -name filename` inquiries on AlmaLinux 8 in SSH as root
the `sudo find / -name filename` command actually finds the files in addition to the invalid argument

I would just ignore the invalid argument on AlmaLinux 8, but, sometimes the
`sudo find / -name filename` command doesn't find the file even though the file is definitely on the server

`sudo find . -name filename`
does not find any files on either Centos 7 or AlmaLinux 8, even though the file is definitely on the servers.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
Audrey

Comment: This is mostly a duplicate of [Permission Denied while trying to Find file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/471026) but that other question has no satisfactory answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of questions here. Good practice is to ask only one question at a time.

### errors in output on sudo find / -name filename

The `/proc` filesystem shows you a representation of the running processes on the system. As these processes finish, the directories under /proc are removed. `find` reads a directory, then for each entry it checks to see if the entry is a directory. If so, it processes it. After it has processed such a sub-directory it continues. If it is looking at say `/proc/17` it may find entries `fd` and `fdinfo` which are directories. It will then process `/proc/17/fd`. Suppose process 17 exits. After processing  `/proc/17/fd` it goes to process `/proc/17/fdinfo`, but `/proc/17` and everything under it has gone, so find issues an error message saying it can't find `/proc/17/fdinfo`.

### sometimes `sudo find / -name filename` doesn't find the file

There is not enough information to help you with this.

### `sudo find . -name filename` does not find any files

Here you are starting with the current directory, so there isn't a file called `filename` under the current directory.

### Find might be the wrong tool.

Depending on what you are wanting to do, it might be that a command like `locate` might be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

You may have two problems.
The first is that you are scanning `/proc` you should exclude it.
I did the same on my rig. And found this error-message on one process. The process was a zombie. Check the process's status. `cat /proc/«pid»/status`. The same error could happen if a process exits while being processed.

I won't answer the other bit. An only one question per question.

Comment: In the command
sudo find / -name filename
filename is just an example of a filename. WHen I run the command - I use the actual file name.

sudo find / -name filename should be consistent with ir't response.

I will see what I can figure out

Comment: I don't grok your comment: most of what you said I already grok (except the word ir't: I have no idea what this word is). I don't see how the comment relates to the answer. The answer still stands.